# Parametrization of primitive Pythagorean triples

Tags: optimization, primitive, pythagorean

I have already written an algorithm to find integer Pythagorean triples, but unfortunately the algorithm runs at O(n^3). Does anyone know how to use parametrization to find Pythagorean triples? If so, can you explain this process to me?

Comment: What do you mean "find triples"? Have you used Euclid's formula to generate triples?

Comment: Yep... a^2 + b^2 = c^2 but this equation is computationally expensive... O(n^3)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to perform necromancy, but take a look at this article published in Mathematics Teacher several years ago: http://www.scribd.com/doc/191694547/Calculating-Pythagorean-Triples

It might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Euclid's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) for generating primitive Pythagorean triples:

for all integer n, m = n + 1 + 2 * p (m - n is odd), and m and n are coprime:

a = m<sup>2</sup>-n<sup>2</sup>

b = 2 * m * n

c = m<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>2</sup>

Comment: yes i know about this, but it will not find ALL pythagorean triples. i was looking for something faster than a^2 + b^2 = c^2

Comment: wikipedia says that this formula generates all primitive triples. Topic title is about primitive ones, isn't it?